Probability of selecting three dice rolls that sum to 6 from Six rolls
I have a question related to dice. Suppose there are 6 dice, and each die is rolled to receive a random value. Let the set of values obtained be represented as $\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_6\}$.
The problem I'm trying to solve is: What is the probability that, among the 6 random numbers obtained from the dice, there exists at least one subset of three numbers whose sum equals 6?
Here’s how I approached the problem:
The probability that the sum of three dice equals 6 is $10/216$.
The number of ways to choose 3 numbers from 6 is $6 \choose 3$.
Therefore, the probability can be computed as $1 - (1 - 10/216)^{20}$.
Thus, the probability that at least one subset of three numbers sums to 6 is $61.25$%.
To verify this, I wrote a program to simulate this process, but the actual value I obtained was quite different from my theoretical result.
Both checking all possible cases and running a simulation 100,000 times gave me a result of approximately $41$%.
Why is there such a discrepancy between the theoretical calculation and the actual result? How can I reconcile this difference?
Here is the code I used:
import math 
import random 
import os 
import itertools

n = 6 
m = 3 
t = 6
print(f'Probability that the sum of {m} dice out of {n} dice is {t}')

dice = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
hap = 0
total = 0
ALL_Events = [[]]
for i in range(m):
    ALL_Events = [E + [e] for e in dice for E in ALL_Events]

for E in ALL_Events:
    if t == sum(E):
        hap += 1
    total += 1

one_set_prob = hap / total
print(f'Probability that the sum of {m} dice is {t} : {hap}/{total} = {one_set_prob * 100:.2f}%')

com = math.comb(n, m)
calc_prob = 1 - ((1 - one_set_prob) ** com)
print(f'Probability that the sum of {m} dice out of {n} is {t} (calculated): {calc_prob * 100:.2f}% (= 1 - {1 - one_set_prob:.4f} ^ {com})')

random.seed(os.urandom(16))
hap = 0
total = 0
for i in range(100000):
    E = [random.choice(dice) for _ in range(n)]
    for e in itertools.combinations(E, m):
        if t == sum(e):
            hap += 1
            break
    total += 1

test_prob = hap / total
print(f'Probability that the sum of {m} dice out of {n} is {t} (test): {test_prob * 100:.2f}%')

hap = 0
total = 0
ALL_Events = [[]]
for i in range(n):
    ALL_Events = [E + [e] for e in dice for E in ALL_Events]

for E in ALL_Events:
    for e in itertools.combinations(E, m):
        if t == sum(e):
            hap += 1
            break
    total += 1

real_prob = hap / total
print(f'Probability that the sum of {m} dice out of {n} is {t} (actual value): {real_prob * 100:.2f}%')

```


Isn't it easier to just list all 19192  configurations (of 6^6=46656 total)  for which there is a subset satisfying the required condition, instead of simulations? Hence the probability is exactly 19192/6^6.

@vanderWolf Thanks for the suggestion! My goal, however, is to generalize the problem. I used the 6-dice, 3-subset case as an example, but I'm interested in finding the probability that, for n dice, there exists a subset of m dice whose sum equals t. Any insights on generalizing this approach would be appreciated!

@vanderWolf I was also curious why there was a discrepancy between my mathematical calculation and the simulation results.

Regarding large $n$  and the subset size of $m$: if $n\to\infty$ but $m$ is fixed and $t\le m\le 6m$, then the probability will go to one (law of large numbers), but there can be more intricate situations, e.g. when we have some functions $m(n)$ and $t(n)$ and to see what happens as $n\to\infty$....

Intermediate result 10/216 : ok.  When we repeat an experience 20 times, all independant each other, formula $1-(1-p)^{20}$ is ok. But your 20 experience are not independant. If dice A,B,C have value 1,2,3, it is a success, and I am highly favorite to have also a succes with (A,B,D) or (A,C,E) or...

In the general case, even the deterministic subset sum is a well-known NP-complete problem (though only weakly so).

This answer is an explicit application of the Inclusion-Exclusion referred to in the answer of mathperson314.  See this article for an
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see this answer for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion formula.
Let $~S~$ denote the collection of all possible ways of rolling the $~6~$ dice.  Then $~| ~S ~| = 6^6.$
Let $~S_1~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ where $~3~$ of the dice showed [1::1::4].
Let $~S_2~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ where $~3~$ of the dice showed [2::2::2].
Let $~S_3~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ where $~3~$ of the dice showed [1::2::3].
Then, the desired computation of the probability is
$$\frac{| ~S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 ~|}{| ~S ~|} = \frac{| ~S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 ~|}{6^6}. \tag1 $$
By Inclusion-Exclusion theory, the numerator in (1) above is equivalent to
$$\left\{ ~| ~S_1 ~| + | ~S_2 ~| + | ~S_3 ~| ~\right\}$$
$$- ~\left\{ ~| ~S_1 \cap S_2 ~| + | ~S_1 \cap S_3 ~| + | ~S_2 \cap S_3 ~| ~\right\} $$
$$+ ~| ~S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 ~|.$$
So, the entire problem reduces to analytically computing the $~7~$ terms above.
Some of these $~7~$ terms will individually be computed by Inclusion-Exclusion.

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~| ~S_1 ~|}$
[1::1::4]
Let $~A~$ denote the set of all dice rolls.
Let $~A_1~$ denote the subset of $~A~$ that does not contain at least $~2~$ 1's.
Let $~A_2~$ denote the subset of $~A~$ that does not contain a 4.
Then
$$|~S_1~| = [ ~| ~A ~| - | ~A_1 \cup A_2 ~| ~]$$
$$= [ ~| ~A ~| - | ~A_1 ~| - | ~A_2 ~| + | ~A_1 \cap A_2 ~]$$
$$= 6^6$$
$$- [ ~5^6 + (6 \times 5^5) ~]$$
$$- 5^6$$
$$+ [ ~4^6 + (6 \times 4^5) ~]$$
$$= [ ~46656 + 4096 + 6144 ~] - [ ~15625 + 18750 + 15625] = 6896.$$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~| ~S_2 ~|}$
[2::2::2]
The number of ways of having less than 3 2's is
$$5^6 + (6 \times 5^5) + (15 \times 5^4)$$
$$ = 70 \times 625 = 43750.$$
Then
$$| ~S_2 ~| = 6^6 - 43750 = 46656 - 43750 = 2906.$$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~| ~S_3 ~|}$
[1::2::3]
Let $~A~$ denote the set of all dice rolls.
Let $~A_1~$ denote the subset of $~A~$ that does not contain at least $~1~$ 1.
Let $~A_2~$ denote the subset of $~A~$ that does not contain at least $~1~$ 2.
Let $~A_3~$ denote the subset of $~A~$ that does not contain at least $~1~$ 3.
Then
$$|~S_3~| = [ ~| ~A ~| - | ~A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 ~| ~]$$
$$= [ ~| ~A ~| $$
$$ - \left\{ ~| ~A_1 ~| - | ~A_2 ~| + | ~A_3 ~| ~\right\} $$
$$ + \left\{ ~| ~A_1 \cap A_2 ~| - | ~A_1 \cap A_3 ~| + | ~A_2 \cap A_3 ~| ~\right\} $$
$$- | ~A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 ~|$$
$$= 6^6 - [ ~3 \times 5^6 ~] + [ ~3 \times 4^6 ~] - [3^6] = 11340.
$$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~| ~S_1 \cap S_2 ~|}$
[1::1::4] :: [2::2::2]
$$| ~S_1 \cap S_2 ~| = \binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{1} = 60.$$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~| ~S_1 \cap S_3 ~|}$
[1::1::4] :: [1::2::3]
The direct approach is easiest here:

1 :: 1 :: 4 :: 2 :: 3 :: [ add 1] 
$\displaystyle 6 \times 5 \times 4 = 120.$

1 :: 1 :: 4 :: 2 :: 3 :: [ add 2] 
$\displaystyle \binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{1} = 180.$

1 :: 1 :: 4 :: 2 :: 3 :: [ add 3] 
$\displaystyle \binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{1} = 180.$

1 :: 1 :: 4 :: 2 :: 3 :: [ add 4] 
$\displaystyle \binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{1} = 180.$

1 :: 1 :: 4 :: 2 :: 3 :: [ add 5 or 6] 
$\displaystyle \binom{6}{2} \times 4! \times 2 = 720.$


$$| ~S_1 \cap S_3 ~| = 120 + (3 \times 180) + 720 = 1380.$$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~| ~S_2 \cap S_3 ~|}$
[2::2::2] :: [1::2::3]
The direct approach is easiest here:

2 :: 2 :: 2 :: 1 :: 3 :: [ add 1] 
$\displaystyle \binom{6}{3} \times \binom{3}{2} = 60.$

2 :: 2 :: 2 :: 1 :: 3 :: [ add 2] 
$\displaystyle \binom{6}{4} \times \binom{2}{1} = 30.$

2 :: 2 :: 2 :: 1 :: 3 :: [ add 3] 
$\displaystyle \binom{6}{3} \times \binom{3}{2} = 60.$

2 :: 2 :: 2 :: 1 :: 3 :: [ add 4, 5, or 6] 
$\displaystyle \binom{6}{3} \times 3! \times 3 = 360.$


$$| ~S_2 \cap S_3 ~| = 60 + 30 + 60 + 360 = 510.$$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~| ~S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 ~|}$
[1::1::4] :: [2::2::2] :: [1::2::3]
1::1::2::2::2::3::4 -- not possible.
$$| ~S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 ~| = 0.$$

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$
$$\left\{ ~| ~S_1 ~| + | ~S_2 ~| + | ~S_3 ~| ~\right\}$$
$$- ~\left\{ ~| ~S_1 \cap S_2 ~| + | ~S_1 \cap S_3 ~| + | ~S_2 \cap S_3 ~| ~\right\} $$
$$+ ~| ~S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 ~|$$
$$= \left\{ ~6896 + 2906 + 11340 ~\right\}$$
$$- \left\{ ~60 + 1380 + 510 ~\right\}$$
$$+ \left\{ ~0 ~\right\}$$
$$ = 19192.$$
Therefore, the probability of being able to find a suitable subset of 3 dice is
$$\frac{19192}{6^6} = \frac{19192}{46656} = \frac{2399}{5832}.$$

Congratulations on getting through the calculation I was too scared/lazy to work through.

Let $E_{ijk}$ be the event that $a_i+a_j+a_k=6$. The events $E_{ijk}$ are not independent, which is required to use the product rule for probabilities $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.
For instance: If $E_{ijk}=6$ then $a_i, a_j$ are small so it is far more likely that $E_{ijl}=6$ for another $l$.
To reconcile the difference and calculate the exact probability would be hard and require using conditional probability, or maybe inclusion exclusion.
Let events $A_i$ be defined as follows:

There are (at least) three $2$'s.

There is a $1,2,3$.

There is a $4$ and two $1$'s.


There are no other ways to produce a sum of 6 from three dice.
Then could you use inclusion-exclusion to calculate $\Pr(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)$?
Note that $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) > 0$ because you might roll $1,1,2,2,2,3,4$. So this requires some work.
Also $P(A_1)$ is the probability that a binomial random variable $B(6,1/6)$ is at least $3$, which is a rather complicated expression to say the least. $P(A_2)$, $P(A_3)$ are even harder to express.
Another approach might be to do inclusion-exclusion on the $E_{ijk}$. For instance, what is $P(E_{123} \cap E_{124})$? This will require more layers, but might actually end up being easier.

Thanks for your answer!
First, I used inclusion-exclusion as you mentioned, but since all intersections are 0, the result still matches my original calculation of $10/216$.
Second, shouldn't we also consider the combinations when selecting 3 dice from 6?

@pioneer See edit for your first question.
The different combinations were implicit in my definitions of the $A_i$. For instance $A_1$ is three twos, in any position.
